# Introducing synonyms for "auto"

Tags: c++, coding-style, auto

Introducing synonyms for "auto"

I'd like to use ["Almost always auto"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) style with C++, but in a more descriptive form, reflecting the semantics of initialization.
To do it I want to introduce synonyms for 4 distinct uses of auto.
The general idea can be understood from the example:

```
#define Val const auto // initialize (immutable) value
#define MVal auto // initialize mutable value
#define Ref const auto& // initialize (immutable) reference 
#define MRef auto&& // initialize mutable reference

Val num = 2 + 2;

MVal count = 0;
++count;

Ref widget = GetWidget();

MRef gadget = GetGadget();
gadget.ChangeState();
```

The several questions arise:

**Q1**: Can the synonyms be introduced without macros?
**Q2**: If macros are inevitable, how do I mitigate the harm from using them (assuming the synonyms should be really short)?
**Q3** (primarily opinion based): Is it a good idea at all (compared to naked AAA-style) from a readability/style point of view?
**Q4** (insane): Are there any fundamental reasons to disallow auto in typedefs (implementability, bad interaction with other features)? (Assuming "typedef auto" is available the problem can be solved trivially)

Comment: Q4. Since `auto` is not the name of a type, you can't introduce a new name using `typedef`. `typedef` does not work by text substitution, unlike macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. No.
Q2. By using them as little as possible.
Q3. Quite bad. C++ programmers are used to a given syntax.
Q4. I don't see what you want there, or why.

Comment: +1, agree, such synonyms would be misleading at best. `const auto&` is pretty self documenting.

Answer (score 3):

Q1. yes synonyms can be introduced in this way. Q2. Use ALLUPPERCASE to follow the convention. Q3. But generally it is not a good idea and I would find more readable `const auto` than `VAL` Q4. I think it is not supported because typedef is a defined type, and `const auto` is not.